# Finding peaks in an Audio spectrogram

Tags: audio, dsp-core, peak-detection

I'm using gist.github.com/sixtenbe/1178136#file-peakdetect-py to find maximum peaks in my spectrogram.

I used

```
_max, _min = peakdetect.peakdetect(array, lookahead=300, delta=0.3)
```

I get the following peaks. x_axis = time, y_axis = frequency

[image]

As you can see in the image, the peaks are not evenly spread out. All the points are skewed towards frequency axis. My array is in this format: [1, 2, 3 , 0 , 1, 3, 4]. It's 2D time+frequency array flattened into 1D array.

What can I do to show the image like this where the peaks are spread out evenly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try flattening your 2D array along the Y or frequency axis instead of along the X or time axis before doing the peak detect.